# How does the `for` loop work on dictionaries specifically

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, dictionary

I was wondering how exactly the `for` loop accesses keys in a dictionary ?
does it call `dict.keys()` and iterate through that list ?

The reason I'm asking is that I want to query a dictionary's key, any key, and I was wondering if there is a difference in performance (aside from visuals and readability) between calling:

```
for key in dict:
    my_func(dict[key])
    break
```

and

```
my_func(dict.keys()[0])
```

Which brought me to the above question - what does python do during a `for` loop on `dict`s, specifically, under the hood?

Comment: `dict[key]` is the same as `dict.keys()[0]` ? in OP `dict[key]` is supposed to return a value, while `dict.keys()[0]` supposed to return a key

Comment: Check out the iterator protocol in [PEP 234](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/)

Comment: Are you asking or telling? Since `dicts` are unordered they wouldn't be the same, if at all by accident or luck or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating `dict` does not call `dict.key()`. The dictionary itself support iteration.

```
>>> iter({'name': 'value'})
<dict_keyiterator object at 0x7f127da89688>
```

BTW, [`dict.keys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) in Python 3.x returns dictionary key view which does not support indexing.

```
>>> {'name': 'value'}.keys()
dict_keys(['name'])
>>> {'name': 'value'}.keys()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

---

If you want to get any key, you can use `next`, `iter`:

```
>>> next(iter({'name': 'value', 'name2': 'another value'}))
'name'

>>> next(iter({}))  # <--  To handle empty case, pass default value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
>>> next(iter({}), 'default value')
'default value'
```